# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghJWi.png) was returned when I tried to connect with server.
Error description is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: Please add more info as to what is the setup exactly etc.

Comment: Go to SQL Server COnfiguration Manager > SQL Server Native client COnfiguration/SQL server Network configuration > Client Protocols > Check whether TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled or not. Check Other points on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: This could be a duplicate of a dozen other questions. The error is pretty clear - the server wasn't found. The most common reasons are the same as always: a misspelled server name, disabled protocols or a firewall that blocks connection to the server. What was your connection string? Is the server running? Have you used the correct Instance name? Error code [occurs only when you try to connect to a named instance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx) but the actual reasons are the same

Comment: @Criesto Why did you rate it -1 please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to check whether SQL SERVER service is running in your system or not .For checking follows below steps in Windows.

Step 1 : Type "window" button + R ,This will open Run prompt.

Step 2: Type "services.msc" in Run prompt and hit the enter.

Step 3: Find SQL SERVER service from there.

Step 4.Start this service.

Following these steps, I have resolved this problem in my machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your SQL Server Service is Running or not
2. if the server is in remote location check port 1433 is not blocked by the firewall.
3. if this is not the default instance, Check SQL Server Browser is running or not
4. Check the network connection on client PC, and verify the connection to the server using PING or TELNET
5. Check whether TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled or not.

for more details [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error **A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections** Go to Sql Server Configuration Manager>>Sql Server Services Sql Server>>Right click on the Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER) and Start the Process.As show below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxQG0.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to your Sql Server running on MacOS via Docker, then make sure that Sql Docker container is running and then you will be able to connect to your Sql Server using Azure Data Studio as shown in attached image [Sql Container inside Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2tE7.jpg)